# Can't use forEach on querySelector

Tags: javascript

I want to use lazy loading effect and in my code everything is going ok, but querySelector section.

I've stored some elements in a variable and I wanna apply observer function on theme.

And I also print every output in console.log to see the things.

But this error happens:

> Uncaught TypeError: imgs.forEach is not a function

This is my code:

```
   const imgs = document.querySelector("[data-src]");

   const options = {
      threshold:1,
   };

   const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries,observer) => {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
        let src = entry.target.getAttribute('data-src'); 
        if(!entry.isIntersecting){
            return;
        }
        entry.target.src=src;
        console.log(entry)
        observer.unobserve(entry.target);
    })

   },options)

   // Probleme is here
   imgs.forEach(img => {
    observer.observe(img);
   })
```

Comment: `querySelector()` will match the first element, whereas `querySelectorAll()` will retrieve all elements

Answer (score 3):

Try with `querySelectorAll` like below code,

```js
const imgs = document.querySelectorAll("[data-src]");
```

as `querySelector` will return single matched element, but `querySelectorAll` will return an [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) of all matched elements.

Answer (score 1):

Use querySelectorAll instead that should fix it

Reference the mdn documentation

> The Document method `querySelectorAll()` returns a static (not live)
> NodeList representing a list of the document's elements that match the
> specified group of selectors.

instead of

```
   const imgs = document.querySelector("[data-src]");
```

try this

```
   const imgs = document.querySelectorAll("[data-src]");
```

Answer (score 0):

Although for some browser using querySelectorAll(selector).forEach() will work. But it is [not supported by all browsers](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/loop-queryselectorall-matches/). So the safe way to do this is using a for loop for looping over the NodeList. So you should do something like this,

```
const imgs = document.querySelector("[data-src]");
// other coddes...
for(let i = 0; i<imgs.length; i++) {
   // your code.
}
```

I think this will be the safest way.

Answer (score 0):

```
Document.querySelector()
```

returns a single element and you cannot loop over a single element.

```
document.querySelectorAll()
```

returns all the elements with the class, id, tagname etc provided in the parenthesis.